# Maximum number of primary partitions?

Tags: linux, operating-system, partitioning

I am reading about partitioning in Linux, and I found out that it is not possible to create an "infinite" number of primary partitions, as I had thought. So, why is the maximum number of primary (non-logical) physical partitions 4?

Comment: Even if a specific partition table format allowed it, how would you fit an "infinite" number of primary partitions on a hard disk with finite available storage?

Comment: that's why i' saying "infinite" and not infinite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a Linux restriction, it's a restriction of the [MBR partition layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). The original MBR spec fit the partition layout into a single 512 byte sector, and there was only room to define four "primary" partitions there. Various nonstandard extensions exist allowing more than four partitions in MBR, but the classical spec only allotted for four.

["Extended boot records"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record) are a fairly common way of extending MBR past its first four primary partitions. One partition entry in the MBR partition table is actually a pointer to another partition table. This second partition table can have a pointer into a third, etc etc, giving, in principle, an unlimited number of extended partitions. However, since these extended partitions are not defined inside the main MBR, they are not primary partitions, and you typically cannot boot from them.

Switching to a more modern standard, such as [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), removes this restriction -- but may not be compatible with some motherboards and operating systems. For example, Windows does not support EFI, the modern spec underlying GPT, unless you are running a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: What about the number of logical partitions? Does that have any constraints?

Comment: I don't believe the number of logical partitions has a limit. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Features), `If the minimum size of 16,384 bytes is allocated for the partition entry array, and the default size of 128 bytes is used for each partition entry, then the maximum number of partitions is limited to 128.`  If I read that correctly, you can have 128 "primary" partitions.

Answer (score 6):

Its 4. It is a limitation of MBR.

If you want more partitions, you can create three primary and one extended partition.

Inside extended partition, you can create as many logical partitions.

Hope it helps.